# How can I check if an event was executed?

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to understand how to know that an event was triggered in yii2, and if it got executed correctly.
So I created an event trigger in `yii\base\Controller` named `EVENT_CONTROLLER_INDEX` like this:

```
const EVENT_CONTROLLER_INDEX='entry-index';

public function render($view, $params = [])
{
    if($view=='index') {
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_CONTROLLER_INDEX);
    }
    $content = $this->getView()->render($view, $params, $this);
    return $this->renderContent($content);
}
```

Now I want to know where and how can I check it if this event happened?

Comment: can you post whole controller?

Comment: One warning: Never change framework file!

Comment: I don’t think this question should be down voted it’s a good question. It only required some editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use loggin and the debug bar.

Check https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-logging

On your event add a line like

```
Yii::debug('my event executed ');
```

Ones executed search for the printed text on the debug bar on the logs section. Also you may find it in the log file.

More on debug bar here:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/blob/master/README.md

So, using loggin and debugbar you will have access to a very powerful tool that will allow to check everything.

[image: debug bar]

Take some time to read about logs usage and debugbar and take advantage of them.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to keep my motive, your answer was helpful.